# standard way of adding html data attribute in html tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding an HTML data attribute, but I am confused about what the standard convestion is regarding the data attribute name. I am understand single-word data attributes (`data-name=""` or `data-id=""`) etc, but what is the convention if I use more than one word in data attribute name? Do I separate the two words, (`data-product_id=""` `or data-product-id=""`), or some form of camel-casing like: `data-productID=""`?

Comment: When in doubt, refer to the spec - sometimes, though not always, the spec will contain one or more naming conventions. If it contains more than one, you'll need to make a decision yourself and stick with it: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data attributes should probably use hyphen-separated words, like `data-product-id`. This allows them to be automatically translated to camelCase when accessing them in Javascript via `dataset` (as most Javascript variables are generally expected to be in camelCase):

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(div.dataset.productId);
```

```html
<div data-product-id=5></div>
```

Using uppercase to indicate word separation isn't a great idea, because it'll be lost when checking the `dataset`, which will significantly harm readability with multiple words when the attribute is long:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(div.dataset);
```

```html
<div data-productID=5></div>
```

Using an underscore in the data attribute would result in the dataset property having an underscore too, which is a *bit* odd, since you'll probably have to translate it to camelCase afterwards to keep in line with variable naming conventions:

```js
const [div1, div2] = document.querySelectorAll('div');

(() => {
  // a bit verbose:
  const productId = div1.dataset.product_id;
  console.log(productId);
})();
(() => {
  // more consise and consistent
  // when the variable name is the same as the property name:
  const { productId } = div2.dataset;
  console.log(productId);
})();
```

```html
<div data-product_id=5></div>
<div data-product-id=6></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, So using - is the best option ? can you give me a brief of dataset. I am using the .data() of jQuery.

Comment: jQuery tries to do the same thing, see https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2 - casing gets ignored, and dash-separated names turn into camelCase. So no matter whether you're using `.dataset` or jQuery, using dashes as separators looks like the best choice

Comment: Shouldn't this question be closed for producing primarily opinion based answers instead of being answered? The casing of the data-attribute name can be either of the OP's examples. As long as they are consistent with the format, it doesn't really matter what format they use.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson: This answer points out some practical implications of using each option, so to some extent it may or may not matter what format they use. Having said that, it doesn't address the main question per se, but it does add important information that would help them make a conclusion. If the asker refuses to be satisfied with anything other than opinion-based answers (not by refusing to mark this answer as accepted, but by being argumentative in the comments), that's when I'd be OK with closing their question.